# "Quarkus" Unsatisfied dependency for type on project's modules autowired dependencies while using "spring" compatibility extensions

Tags: spring-boot, migration, quarkus

I'm new to Quarkus and I'm validating the migration viability of a quite complex Spring Boot application.

For now, I'm trying to make the first step into Quarkus world, which is to get the application running on Quarkus JVM (non native option) with as little changes as possible.

After dealing with "spring-orm", "spring-jdbc", "spring-web" (client part), "spring-security" and "spring-boot" (autoconfigure and web parts) dependencies not covered by Quarkus spring extensions, now I'm facing Quarkus deployment problems like below:

```
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 8 deployment problems:
Unsatisfied dependency for type <APP_BASE_PACKAGE>.api.rulesengine.service.RulesDomainConfiguratorService and qualifiers
Unsatisfied dependency for type <APP_BASE_PACKAGE>.api.rulesengine.service.RulesEngineService and qualifiers
Unsatisfied dependency for type <APP_BASE_PACKAGE>.api.rulesengine.service.RulesEngineStatisticService and qualifiers
Unsatisfied dependency for type <APP_BASE_PACKAGE>.api.rulesengine.jmx.DynamicJmxConfigurationProperties and qualifiers
```

I've noticed that it's possible to solve almost all deployment problems above by the addition of "@ApplicationScoped" (as suggested by @Turing85 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59795240/quarkus-arc-unsatisfied-dependency-problem)), but I've got really lost by those deployment failures conditions, and the necessity of the annotation addition, for a number of reasons, being some of them:

1- Those deployment errors are regarding services and repositories implemented on diferent modules of the same project (which are all indexed with jandex);

2- One deployment problem couldn't be solved by the addition of "@ApplicationScoped" on quite similar condition of one that was solved;

3- I was not expecting to get any errors regarding spring dependencies, or have to add any CDI annotation, considering that I'm using "quarkus-spring-*" compatibility extensions; and,

4- The deployment indicated problems cover only a small subset of all spring dependencies of the whole project. Why just them?

Am I missing something here?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

After some attempts to solve the problem I decided to give a try and replace the "jandex-maven-plugin" by the "resources/META-INF/beans.xml" files (as the dependencies indexation option) and all unsatisfied dependencies regarding children modules of the application just vanished.